# Apply Javascript code to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to apply a specific Javascript code to multiple elements at the same time, How i could do this? 
I've a page which includes forms for adding students, Each student has his own birthday, I've 3 selectors for choosing (Day, Month and year), So 3 selectors and each selector has its value. 
I want to copy these selectors values to another input, on each change happens to this selectors the data will be updated in that input, I've succeeded to do it, But want to apply this to all elements on the page, There could be 50 students in each page and the code runs only for the first element.

Here's the function which i call on every change happens to each separate selector:

```
    function copyDiv() {

            var e = document.getElementById("dayb");
            var dayb = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

            var e2 = document.getElementById("monthb");
            var monthb = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;

            var e3 = document.getElementById("yearb");
            var yearb = e3.options[e3.selectedIndex].value;
         var typedb = document.getElementById("typedbirthday");

         typedb.value = dayb + " / " + monthb + " / " + yearb;
}
```

Attached picture of the form:

[image]

Here's the HTML code too:

```
<div class="f-table-bnp">
                        <div class="f-table-header">
                            <div class="table-h-c1">Num.</div>
                            <div class="table-h-c2">Name</div>
                            <div class="table-h-c3">Add Picture</div>
                            <div class="table-h-c4">Birthday</div>
                            <div class="table-h-c5"></div>
                        </div>


                            <div class="f-table-row1">



        <div class="table-h-c1 table-r1-c1">
            <div class="r1-c1-text member_number"> 1 </div>
            <div class="r1-c1-input"><input type="checkbox" checked=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-h-c2 table-r1-c2">
            <div class="r1-c2-input">
                <input type="text" name="family[1][member][1][name]" value="asdsd" placeholder="Add name here" onclick="placeholder=''" onblur="placeholder='Add name here'">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-h-c3 table-r1-c3">
            <input type="hidden" name="fr" value="11">
            <div class="r1-c3-btn"><input type="file" class="photoimg" id="11" data-family-id="1" data-member-id="1"></div>
            <div id="img11" class="r1-c3-img">

                <input type="hidden" name="family[1][member][1][photo]" value="uploads/14118608306_10200384523890033_1961108332_n.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>



<div class="table-h-c4 table-r1-c4">


                                        <div class="select-date-row">
                                            <select name="family[1][member][1][dob][day]" id="dayb" onchange="copyDiv()">
                                                <option value="">Date</option>
                                                <option>1</option>
                                                <option>2</option>
                                                <option>3</option>
                                                <option>4</option>
                                                <option>5</option>
                                                <option>6</option>
                                                <option>7</option>
                                                <option>8</option>
                                                <option>9</option>
                                                <option>10</option>
                                                <option>11</option>
                                                <option>12</option>
                                                <option>13</option>
                                                <option>14</option>
                                                <option>15</option>
                                                <option>16</option>
                                                <option>17</option>
                                                <option>18</option>
                                                <option>19</option>
                                                <option>20</option>
                                                <option>21</option>
                                                <option>21</option>
                                                <option>23</option>
                                                <option>24</option>
                                                <option>25</option>
                                                <option>26</option>
                                                <option>27</option>
                                                <option>28</option>
                                                <option>29</option>
                                                <option>30</option>
                                                <option>31</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <select name="family[1][member][1][dob][month]" id="monthb" onchange="copyDiv()">
                                                <option value="">Month</option>
                                                <option>1</option>
                                                <option>2</option>
                                                <option>2</option>
                                                <option>4</option>
                                                <option>5</option>
                                                <option>6</option>
                                                <option>7</option>
                                                <option>8</option>
                                                <option>9</option>
                                                <option>10</option>
                                                <option>11</option>
                                                <option>12</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <select name="family[1][member][1][dob][year]" id="yearb" onchange="copyDiv()">
                                                <option value="">Year</option>
                                                <option>1990</option>


                                                 <option> 1900 </option> <option> 1901 </option> <option> 1902 </option> <option> 1903 </option> <option> 1904 </option> <option> 1905 </option> <option> 1906 </option> <option> 1907 </option> <option> 1908 </option> <option> 1909 </option> <option> 1910 </option> <option> 1911 </option> <option> 1912 </option> <option> 1913 </option> <option> 1914 </option> <option> 1915 </option> <option> 1916 </option> <option> 1917 </option> <option> 1918 </option> <option> 1919 </option> <option> 1920 </option> <option> 1921 </option> <option> 1922 </option> <option> 1923 </option> <option> 1924 </option> <option> 1925 </option> <option> 1926 </option> <option> 1927 </option> <option> 1928 </option> <option> 1929 </option> <option> 1930 </option> <option> 1931 </option> <option> 1932 </option> <option> 1933 </option> <option> 1934 </option> <option> 1935 </option> <option> 1936 </option> <option> 1937 </option> <option> 1938 </option> <option> 1939 </option> <option> 1940 </option> <option> 1941 </option> <option> 1942 </option> <option> 1943 </option> <option> 1944 </option> <option> 1945 </option> <option> 1946 </option> <option> 1947 </option> <option> 1948 </option> <option> 1949 </option> <option> 1950 </option> <option> 1951 </option> <option> 1952 </option> <option> 1953 </option> <option> 1954 </option> <option> 1955 </option> <option> 1956 </option> <option> 1957 </option> <option> 1958 </option> <option> 1959 </option> <option> 1960 </option> <option> 1961 </option> <option> 1962 </option> <option> 1963 </option> <option> 1964 </option> <option> 1965 </option> <option> 1966 </option> <option> 1967 </option> <option> 1968 </option> <option> 1969 </option> <option> 1970 </option> <option> 1971 </option> <option> 1972 </option> <option> 1973 </option> <option> 1974 </option> <option> 1975 </option> <option> 1976 </option> <option> 1977 </option> <option> 1978 </option> <option> 1979 </option> <option> 1980 </option> <option> 1981 </option> <option> 1982 </option> <option> 1983 </option> <option> 1984 </option> <option> 1985 </option> <option> 1986 </option> <option> 1987 </option> <option> 1988 </option> <option> 1989 </option> <option> 1990 </option> <option> 1991 </option> <option> 1992 </option> <option> 1993 </option> <option> 1994 </option> <option> 1995 </option> <option> 1996 </option> <option> 1997 </option> <option> 1998 </option> <option> 1999 </option> <option> 2000 </option> <option> 2001 </option> <option> 2002 </option> <option> 2003 </option> <option> 2004 </option> <option> 2005 </option> <option> 2006 </option> <option> 2007 </option> <option> 2008 </option> <option> 2009 </option> <option> 2010 </option> <option> 2011 </option> <option> 2012 </option> <option> 2013 </option> <option> 2014 </option>                                                

                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="type-date">
                                            <input id="typedbirthday" name="family[1][member][1][dob][date]" value="4 / 11 / 1912" type="text" placeholder="Or type your date here" onclick="placeholder=''" onblur="placeholder='Or type your date here'">
                                        </div>
                                    </div> 
        <div class="table-h-c5 table-r1-c5">
            <p class="deleterow" data-id="1"><a href="#"><img src="images/delete-icon.png" alt="">Delete</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="f-table-row1">



        <div class="table-h-c1 table-r1-c1">
            <div class="r1-c1-text member_number"> 2 </div>
            <div class="r1-c1-input"><input type="checkbox" checked=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-h-c2 table-r1-c2">
            <div class="r1-c2-input">
                <input type="text" name="family[1][member][2][name]" value="asdasdasdas" placeholder="Add name here" onclick="placeholder=''" onblur="placeholder='Add name here'">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-h-c3 table-r1-c3">
            <input type="hidden" name="fr" value="12">
            <div class="r1-c3-btn"><input type="file" class="photoimg" id="12" data-family-id="1" data-member-id="2"></div>
            <div id="img12" class="r1-c3-img">
                <img style="width:68;height:70;" width="68" height="70" src="images/upload-img.png" alt="">
                <input type="hidden" name="family[1][member][2][photo]" value="">
            </div>
        </div>




<div class="table-h-c4 table-r1-c4">


                                        <div class="select-date-row">
                                            <select name="family[1][member][2][dob][day]" id="dayb" onchange="copyDiv()">
                                                <option value="">Date</option>
                                                <option>1</option>
                                                <option>2</option>
                                                <option>3</option>
                                                <option>4</option>
                                                <option>5</option>
                                                <option>6</option>
                                                <option>7</option>
                                                <option>8</option>
                                                <option>9</option>
                                                <option>10</option>
                                                <option>11</option>
                                                <option>12</option>
                                                <option>13</option>
                                                <option>14</option>
                                                <option>15</option>
                                                <option>16</option>
                                                <option>17</option>
                                                <option>18</option>
                                                <option>19</option>
                                                <option>20</option>
                                                <option>21</option>
                                                <option>21</option>
                                                <option>23</option>
                                                <option>24</option>
                                                <option>25</option>
                                                <option>26</option>
                                                <option>27</option>
                                                <option>28</option>
                                                <option>29</option>
                                                <option>30</option>
                                                <option>31</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <select name="family[1][member][2][dob][month]" id="monthb" onchange="copyDiv()">
                                                <option value="">Month</option>
                                                <option>1</option>
                                                <option>2</option>
                                                <option>2</option>
                                                <option>4</option>
                                                <option>5</option>
                                                <option>6</option>
                                                <option>7</option>
                                                <option>8</option>
                                                <option>9</option>
                                                <option>10</option>
                                                <option>11</option>
                                                <option>12</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <select name="family[1][member][2][dob][year]" id="yearb" onchange="copyDiv()">
                                                <option value="">Year</option>
                                                <option>1990</option>


                                                 <option> 1900 </option> <option> 1901 </option> <option> 1902 </option> <option> 1903 </option> <option> 1904 </option> <option> 1905 </option> <option> 1906 </option> <option> 1907 </option> <option> 1908 </option> <option> 1909 </option> <option> 1910 </option> <option> 1911 </option> <option> 1912 </option> <option> 1913 </option> <option> 1914 </option> <option> 1915 </option> <option> 1916 </option> <option> 1917 </option> <option> 1918 </option> <option> 1919 </option> <option> 1920 </option> <option> 1921 </option> <option> 1922 </option> <option> 1923 </option> <option> 1924 </option> <option> 1925 </option> <option> 1926 </option> <option> 1927 </option> <option> 1928 </option> <option> 1929 </option> <option> 1930 </option> <option> 1931 </option> <option> 1932 </option> <option> 1933 </option> <option> 1934 </option> <option> 1935 </option> <option> 1936 </option> <option> 1937 </option> <option> 1938 </option> <option> 1939 </option> <option> 1940 </option> <option> 1941 </option> <option> 1942 </option> <option> 1943 </option> <option> 1944 </option> <option> 1945 </option> <option> 1946 </option> <option> 1947 </option> <option> 1948 </option> <option> 1949 </option> <option> 1950 </option> <option> 1951 </option> <option> 1952 </option> <option> 1953 </option> <option> 1954 </option> <option> 1955 </option> <option> 1956 </option> <option> 1957 </option> <option> 1958 </option> <option> 1959 </option> <option> 1960 </option> <option> 1961 </option> <option> 1962 </option> <option> 1963 </option> <option> 1964 </option> <option> 1965 </option> <option> 1966 </option> <option> 1967 </option> <option> 1968 </option> <option> 1969 </option> <option> 1970 </option> <option> 1971 </option> <option> 1972 </option> <option> 1973 </option> <option> 1974 </option> <option> 1975 </option> <option> 1976 </option> <option> 1977 </option> <option> 1978 </option> <option> 1979 </option> <option> 1980 </option> <option> 1981 </option> <option> 1982 </option> <option> 1983 </option> <option> 1984 </option> <option> 1985 </option> <option> 1986 </option> <option> 1987 </option> <option> 1988 </option> <option> 1989 </option> <option> 1990 </option> <option> 1991 </option> <option> 1992 </option> <option> 1993 </option> <option> 1994 </option> <option> 1995 </option> <option> 1996 </option> <option> 1997 </option> <option> 1998 </option> <option> 1999 </option> <option> 2000 </option> <option> 2001 </option> <option> 2002 </option> <option> 2003 </option> <option> 2004 </option> <option> 2005 </option> <option> 2006 </option> <option> 2007 </option> <option> 2008 </option> <option> 2009 </option> <option> 2010 </option> <option> 2011 </option> <option> 2012 </option> <option> 2013 </option> <option> 2014 </option>                                                

                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="type-date">
                                            <input id="typedbirthday" name="family[1][member][2][dob][date]" value="5.5.1905" type="text" placeholder="Or type your date here" onclick="placeholder=''" onblur="placeholder='Or type your date here'">
                                        </div>
                                    </div> 
        <div class="table-h-c5 table-r1-c5">
            <p class="deleterow" data-id="1"><a href="#"><img src="images/delete-icon.png" alt="">Delete</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="f-table-row1">



        <div class="table-h-c1 table-r1-c1">
            <div class="r1-c1-text member_number"> 3 </div>
            <div class="r1-c1-input"><input type="checkbox" checked=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-h-c2 table-r1-c2">
            <div class="r1-c2-input">
                <input type="text" name="family[1][member][3][name]" value="asdasdsadasdasdadd" placeholder="Add name here" onclick="placeholder=''" onblur="placeholder='Add name here'">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-h-c3 table-r1-c3">
            <input type="hidden" name="fr" value="13">
            <div class="r1-c3-btn"><input type="file" class="photoimg" id="13" data-family-id="1" data-member-id="3"></div>
            <div id="img13" class="r1-c3-img">
                <img style="width:68;height:70;" width="68" height="70" src="images/upload-img.png" alt="">
                <input type="hidden" name="family[1][member][3][photo]" value="">
            </div>
        </div>



<div class="table-h-c4 table-r1-c4">


                                        <div class="select-date-row">
                                            <select name="family[1][member][3][dob][day]" id="dayb" onchange="copyDiv()">
                                                <option value="">Date</option>
                                                <option>1</option>
                                                <option>2</option>
                                                <option>3</option>
                                                <option>4</option>
                                                <option>5</option>
                                                <option>6</option>
                                                <option>7</option>
                                                <option>8</option>
                                                <option>9</option>
                                                <option>10</option>
                                                <option>11</option>
                                                <option>12</option>
                                                <option>13</option>
                                                <option>14</option>
                                                <option>15</option>
                                                <option>16</option>
                                                <option>17</option>
                                                <option>18</option>
                                                <option>19</option>
                                                <option>20</option>
                                                <option>21</option>
                                                <option>21</option>
                                                <option>23</option>
                                                <option>24</option>
                                                <option>25</option>
                                                <option>26</option>
                                                <option>27</option>
                                                <option>28</option>
                                                <option>29</option>
                                                <option>30</option>
                                                <option>31</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <select name="family[1][member][3][dob][month]" id="monthb" onchange="copyDiv()">
                                                <option value="">Month</option>
                                                <option>1</option>
                                                <option>2</option>
                                                <option>2</option>
                                                <option>4</option>
                                                <option>5</option>
                                                <option>6</option>
                                                <option>7</option>
                                                <option>8</option>
                                                <option>9</option>
                                                <option>10</option>
                                                <option>11</option>
                                                <option>12</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <select name="family[1][member][3][dob][year]" id="yearb" onchange="copyDiv()">
                                                <option value="">Year</option>
                                                <option>1990</option>


                                                 <option> 1900 </option> <option> 1901 </option> <option> 1902 </option> <option> 1903 </option> <option> 1904 </option> <option> 1905 </option> <option> 1906 </option> <option> 1907 </option> <option> 1908 </option> <option> 1909 </option> <option> 1910 </option> <option> 1911 </option> <option> 1912 </option> <option> 1913 </option> <option> 1914 </option> <option> 1915 </option> <option> 1916 </option> <option> 1917 </option> <option> 1918 </option> <option> 1919 </option> <option> 1920 </option> <option> 1921 </option> <option> 1922 </option> <option> 1923 </option> <option> 1924 </option> <option> 1925 </option> <option> 1926 </option> <option> 1927 </option> <option> 1928 </option> <option> 1929 </option> <option> 1930 </option> <option> 1931 </option> <option> 1932 </option> <option> 1933 </option> <option> 1934 </option> <option> 1935 </option> <option> 1936 </option> <option> 1937 </option> <option> 1938 </option> <option> 1939 </option> <option> 1940 </option> <option> 1941 </option> <option> 1942 </option> <option> 1943 </option> <option> 1944 </option> <option> 1945 </option> <option> 1946 </option> <option> 1947 </option> <option> 1948 </option> <option> 1949 </option> <option> 1950 </option> <option> 1951 </option> <option> 1952 </option> <option> 1953 </option> <option> 1954 </option> <option> 1955 </option> <option> 1956 </option> <option> 1957 </option> <option> 1958 </option> <option> 1959 </option> <option> 1960 </option> <option> 1961 </option> <option> 1962 </option> <option> 1963 </option> <option> 1964 </option> <option> 1965 </option> <option> 1966 </option> <option> 1967 </option> <option> 1968 </option> <option> 1969 </option> <option> 1970 </option> <option> 1971 </option> <option> 1972 </option> <option> 1973 </option> <option> 1974 </option> <option> 1975 </option> <option> 1976 </option> <option> 1977 </option> <option> 1978 </option> <option> 1979 </option> <option> 1980 </option> <option> 1981 </option> <option> 1982 </option> <option> 1983 </option> <option> 1984 </option> <option> 1985 </option> <option> 1986 </option> <option> 1987 </option> <option> 1988 </option> <option> 1989 </option> <option> 1990 </option> <option> 1991 </option> <option> 1992 </option> <option> 1993 </option> <option> 1994 </option> <option> 1995 </option> <option> 1996 </option> <option> 1997 </option> <option> 1998 </option> <option> 1999 </option> <option> 2000 </option> <option> 2001 </option> <option> 2002 </option> <option> 2003 </option> <option> 2004 </option> <option> 2005 </option> <option> 2006 </option> <option> 2007 </option> <option> 2008 </option> <option> 2009 </option> <option> 2010 </option> <option> 2011 </option> <option> 2012 </option> <option> 2013 </option> <option> 2014 </option>                                                

                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="type-date">
                                            <input id="typedbirthday" name="family[1][member][3][dob][date]" value="" type="text" placeholder="Or type your date here" onclick="placeholder=''" onblur="placeholder='Or type your date here'">
                                        </div>
                                    </div> 
        <div class="table-h-c5 table-r1-c5">
            <p class="deleterow" data-id="1"><a href="#"><img src="images/delete-icon.png" alt="">Delete</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>


                    </div>
```

Comment: show at least part of your html for 2 students

Comment: First, you should change your ids as you're using the same ids in each row. An id has to be unique. Simply change the ids to classes as so far it shouldn't be too much that you have to adjust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementById()` only gets the first element with the specified `id`. Instead, you should determine the `select` elements you wish to handle based on `select` element that was changed.

Personally, I would consider using a library such as jQuery to ease the DOM manipulation, but here's an example of how to do it in plain JavaScript, without any dependencies.

Change all the `onchange="copyDiv()"` in every `select` to `onchange="copyDiv(this)"`

```
<select name="..." id="..." onchange="copyDiv(this)">
```

Then use the following JavaScript:

```
function getSiblings(elem, skip) {
    var r = [],
        n = elem.parentNode.firstChild;

    for ( ; n; n = n.nextSibling ) {
        if ( n.nodeType === 1 && n != skip) {
            r.push( n );
        }
    }

    return r;
}

function copyDiv(elem) {
    var siblings = getSiblings(elem),
        parentSiblings = getSiblings(elem.parentNode),
        typedb, dayb, monthb, yearb;

    for(var i=0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
        if (siblings[i].id === 'dayb') {
            dayb = siblings[i].value;
        }
        if (siblings[i].id === 'monthb') {
            monthb = siblings[i].value;
        }
        if (siblings[i].id === 'yearb') {
            yearb = siblings[i].value;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i < parentSiblings.length; i++) {
        if (parentSiblings[i].className === 'type-date') {
            typedb = parentSiblings[i].children[0];
            typedb.value = dayb + " / " + monthb + " / " + yearb;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is very dependent on your current HTML structure, so changes to your HTML may render this code useless. But at least you have idea on how to tackle your issue.

Here's a simplified working Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyEstilles/15nhktbw/. It only has two rows with `select-date-row` and `type-date`, but it illustrates my solution.